# Vim: Can't get pathogen to load bundles

Tags: vim, ubuntu, pathogen

I've read five other questions about this on Stackoverflow, and github and so on, but have not been able to solve this problem, and am totally lost at this point.

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 with Vim 7.3.

Here's my .vimrc

```
set nocp
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
call pathogen#infect()
colorscheme xoria256
set rnu
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set cindent
set virtualedit=all
```

pathogen.vim is in ~/.vim/autoload and I've got vim-jade and vim-surround in ~/.vim/bundle/

I don't get any errors when I run vim index.jade I just don't have syntax highlighting and I can't use the vim surround commands.

Any help would rock! I've been at this for a few hours.

Comment: I just have the following lines in my .vimrc and stuff works for me: call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

Comment: I just tried that, doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: How did you install vim-jade and vim-surround?

Comment: cd ~/.vim/bundle ...and then... 
git clone git://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-jade.git

Answer (score 1):

You only need one call to pathogen and this must happen before you do `filetype plugin indent on`.

This version of your `~/.vimrc` should work.

```
set nocompatible
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
colorscheme xoria256
set relativenumber
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set cindent
set virtualedit=all
```

Comment: Good point, thanks! Still isn't working though. I've posted some more info on github here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/83#issuecomment-13098223

Comment: You have a lot of *crazy* things in your `runtimepath`: `/var/lib/vim/addons/bundle/*`, `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/bundle/*`, etc. You should stick to one plugin installation method and **not ever touch your system files.** The only `bundle` directory should be `~/.vim/bundle`.

Comment: Totally fair! I'm still learning, and I would love to do a clean install, but I haven't been able to accomplish that either.

Comment: 1. Use Synaptic to remove every package with `vim` in the name. 2. Install the vim-gnome package and all its dependencies. 3. Quit Synaptic. 4. Empty `~/.vim`. 5. Install pathogen and other plugins carefully following their instructions.

Comment: That didn't work. I removed (using the 'remove completely' option) everything with vim in it, and followed your steps in that order, but I still have the same problems, in addition snipmate.vim isn't working. I noticed even after removing everything that my usr/share/vim folder was still full of files and directories unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a directory in bundle with name of your plugin

   mkdir ~/.vim/bundle/surround/
2. Unzip the plugin to the directory, you created.

   cp ~/surround.zip ~/.vim/bundle/surround/
   cd ~/.vim/bundle/surround/
   unzip surround.zip
   rm -rf surround.zip
3. Add these lines to the beginning of the ~/.vimrc

   execute pathogen#infect()
   syntax on
   filetype plugin indent on

Now you will able to use surround.vim plugin.